# Is using low ESL capacitors ever mandatory?

Tags: capacitor

I have recently come across the concept of low ESL capacitors. This was from EEVBlog video "EEVblog #859 - Bypass Capacitor Tutorial". These look like this:

[image]

The pads are on the longer sides so the distance from one pad to the other is small. Is it ever compulsory to use such capacitors? I have never seen them on a PCB yet and never heard of them before.

Comment: It's compulsory if the application requires low ESL.  Microwave and other RF applications come to mind.

Comment: Intel and amd use them on various CPUs, although these days you'll frequently see even lower inductance interdigitated capacitors, which are essentially wide capacitors with the terminals subdivided into alternating positive and negative pads.

Comment: Never heard of interdigitated capacitors, it seems this is even another more superior device. I thought low ESL only mattered for power supply by pass capacitors.

Comment: AMD moved from Interdigitated caps to X2Y caps on Zen4 CPUs.. Those provide yet tighter current loops and hence lower inductance. Note that the via pattern and distribution planes are fundamental ingredients in determining the inductance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they are mandatory and needed, otherwise they would not exist.

If you look at almost any recent or even non-recent PC CPU, they might have capacitors like this on them.

Same might be true for caps for GPU chips or FPGAs, near them on PCB.

These devices can consume a lot of pulsed current at the clock frequency where a lot of transistors switch at the same instant. Or at least at almost the same instant, given that the clocks are at RF frequencies and propagation delays have to be taken into account.

To have low power supply impedance at these high frequencies, low ESL caps might be a necessity to get the needed current without much voltage drop/ripple, and get the needed current quickly enough, so these require low ESR and ESL.

Comment: Just a thought, when we say low ESL, how do we really know if ESL is low enough? I mean we would ideally want to be as close as zero, but is there a way to know if what we have or are able to get is low enough? Won't larger number of higher ESL capacitors also lead to low net ESL?

Comment: That is a good question and there is no simple answer. When impedance fulfills the chip requirements at the required frequency range then it's enough. It's just that only very demanding chips such as CPUs and FPGAs may have these requirements specified. And yes, many normal capacitors in parallel will result in low net ESL. The problem may be, can you fit the required amount of normal caps to be close enough the chip so it works, as the longer the distance is the more you have ESL and ESR just from PCB tracks. For example, Intel has some power distribution network appnotes.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't mandatory necessarily, but you'll need more capacitors if you want the same effect. The ESL parallels to some extent so if you need lower ESL in your application, you'll need more than one capacitor or multiple capacitors. The lower the ESL the better the capacitor will function in the high frequency ranges.

In some applications such as filters to get matching you need XY capacitors with three terminals to lower ESL to the levels that are needed.

Comment: capacitor .. with 3 terminals? Oh, new stuff.

Comment: The have been around for a while. They have two capacitors in the same package, but because the terminals are closer together the ESL is lower and the matching better.